# Convert SQL Server to MySQL inner join error using TOP

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am getting an error "SELECT        top (20) L.load_Number," in the following:

```
INSERT INTO Last_20_Loads 
SELECT        top (20) L.load_Number, count(b.Bales_Per_Hour) AS COUNT_Bales_Per_Hour, sum(b.Bales_Per_Hour) AS SUM_Bales_Per_Hour
FROM Loads AS L INNER JOIN
    Bales AS B ON L.Load_Number = B.Load_Number 
where (status = 7)
GROUP BY l.load_Number
ORDER BY l.load_Number DESC;
```

Why am I getting error.  How to fix?

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: The exact error occurs at L., syntax error, unexpected '.'

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses LIMIT instead of TOP. You should also specify your column names in your INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO Last_20_Loads (load_number, countbales, sumbales)
SELECT L.load_Number, count(b.Bales_Per_Hour) AS COUNT_Bales_Per_Hour, sum(b.Bales_Per_Hour) AS SUM_Bales_Per_Hour
FROM Loads AS L INNER JOIN
Bales AS B ON L.Load_Number = B.Load_Number 
where (status = 7)
GROUP BY l.load_Number
ORDER BY l.load_Number DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

The euivalent of `TOP` is `LIMIT` in mysql.

```
INSERT INTO Last_20_Loads 
SELECT  L.load_Number, 
        count(b.Bales_Per_Hour) AS COUNT_Bales_Per_Hour, 
        sum(b.Bales_Per_Hour) AS SUM_Bales_Per_Hour
FROM    Loads AS L 
        INNER JOIN Bales AS B 
            ON L.Load_Number = B.Load_Number 
where   (status = 7)
GROUP   BY l.load_Number
ORDER   BY l.load_Number DESC
LIMIT   20;
```